# non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame:

Tags: r

```
library(tidyverse)
data1<- read.csv("loss.csv")

attach(data1)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
plot(exret,loss, col="red")
plot(custcomplaint,loss, col="blue")
plot(exdelay,loss, col="green")
boxplot(data1$loss,main="(Yes/No)")
plot(avglawsuits,loss, col="skyblue")

df<- log(data1)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
plot(exret,dfloss, col="red")
plot(custcomplaint,dfloss, col="blue")
plot(exdelay,dfloss, col="green")
boxplot(df$dfloss,main="(Yes/No)")
plot(avglawsuits,dfloss, col="skyblue")

df<- log(data1)
Error in Math.data.frame(data1) :
non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: lowprior
```

I try to draw the relationship between each variable and the loss variable. The lowprior variable only contains yes or no. When I try log data and then try again, r prompts df<- log (data1)

Error in Math.data.frame(data1) :

non-numeric-alike variable(s) in data frame: lowprior
How can I log data

Comment: You need to log each variable separately instead of the whole data frame. `plot(log(exert), log(dfloss))` etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like your data has non-numeric columns, so `log(data)` won't work because you can only `log` numbers. You could log just the numeric columns like this:

```
## base R
log_data = data1
num_cols = sapply(data1, is.numeric)
log_data[num_cols] = lapply(log_data[num_cols], log)

## dplyr
library(dplyr)
log_data = data1 |>
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), log))
```